Extension doesn't work on Puppeteer Cluster
I'm trying to load CapSolver's extension on my browser instances generated with Puppeteer Cluster, but it seems that the extension only works on the about:blank instance (the instance that Puppeteer Cluster creates when you use CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT) and not on the actual browsing instances.

const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

(async () => {
    const pathToExtension = require('path').join(__dirname, 'capsolver');
    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 2,
        puppeteerOptions: {
            headless: false,
            args: [
                `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
                `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
            ],
        },
    });

    await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
        await page.goto(url);
        await delay(60000);
    });

    cluster.queue('http://www.google.com/');
    cluster.queue('http://www.wikipedia.org/');
    // many more pages

    await cluster.idle();
    await cluster.close();
})();

function delay(time) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

